# after filtering the column data in excel file that filter data add to the new column 'comment'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-datareader

Actually i am new to python pandas module. by using pandas i want to filter data in one column and add to the filtered data into new column name like 'comment'. Suppose in one excel file headers be like A,B,C,D and E. in B header has different data like 'python','flask','pandas','python','numpy','pandas','pandas,'python','pandas'. so i want to filter in B header by selecting 'python' that data will be filtered and add data to the new column name like 'comment'.

```
here is my python code:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

source_file = 'C:\\Users\\user98\\Desktop\\excel_1.xlsx'
read_file = pd.read_excel(source_file)
data=read_file[read_file.B== 'python']
read_file['comment']=data
print(read_file)
```

in above code throwing the error like "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1".

in my concern comment column will be added and In B header after selecting the filter using python data will be added to same row in comment line row.

```
for example:  this is excel data set before filtering the B header column by selecting python name in excel file.

  B          comment           
python         python           
pandas         pandas           
numpy          numpy            
python         pandas
pandas         pandas
python         python
```

after filtering the data as shown below like data will be added to both columns for same row numbers.

```
   B         comment
 python       B-python
 python       B-python
 python       B-python
```

Comment: Looks like the entire row `read_file['comment']=data` is not neccesary. Delete it, and see if in `data` you have what you need.

Comment: for above condition  i wanna filter B header column whatever data available with python name and that data will be added new column name like 'comment' column

Comment: not 100% sure what you need but something like `df.loc[df['comment'] == 'python','comment'] = 'B' + df['comment']`?

Comment: @Datanovice... it's not working what you mentioned here.